# How do I export the charts in a spreadsheet as PNGs?

Tags: openoffice-calc, libreoffice

I made a spreadsheet and generated some graphs in Calc. I would like to grab each chart as a PNG (JPG will be fine too) and save them as an individual file so I can post the charts on my blog.

I tried dragging from Calc into the browser post box but unfortunately that didn't work.

Comment: worst case you could take a screen shot, paste into your editor of choice and crop it. but there must be a better way.

Comment: @Xantec: That can be a worst case indeed. But of course it would not work well for huge charts, or if you need a good resolution, for instance for printing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a little long winded, but it's the only way I have found so far.

1. Create the chart as normal in Calc.
2. Select the chart and copy it.
3. Open Draw and paste the chart.
4. Resize to suit your needs.
5. Make sure the chart is selected.
6. Export the Draw page as a PNG making sure to turn on the "Selection" option.

Answer (score 5):

1. Select chart and copy it.
2. Click empty cell
3. Edit / Paste special
4. Choose paste as... GDI Metafile.
5. Copy the just pasted chart
6. Paste into your favourite image editor.
7. Save as PNG.

GDI metafile is an image, not the real plot. Keep the original graph in Calc always.